# nodejs http.request close process when request timeout

Tags: node.js, https, error-handling

```
const request = https.request(options, (response) => {})
request.on('socket', (socket) => {
    socket.setTimeout(100)
    socket.on('timeout', () => {
        console.log(`timeout`.red);
        request.abort()
    })
})
request.on('error', (e) => {
    console.log(`problem with request: ${e.message}`);
});
```

error and kill process.
need to just log error without kill process

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe the timeout is causing your process to exit. Try this code very similar to yours, you can set the timeout to whatever you like to deliberately cause this error. I've modified your code slightly to wait for user input before exiting.

```
const https = require ('https');

const options = {
    hostname: "httpbin.org",
    path: "/ip"
}

var request = https.request(options,  (res) => {
    console.log('statusCode:', res.statusCode);
    res.on('data', (d) => {
        process.stdout.write(d);
    });

});

request.on('socket', (socket) => {
    socket.setTimeout(1000);
    socket.on('timeout', () => {
        console.log(`timeout`.red);
        request.abort()
    })
})

request.on('error', (e) => {
    console.log(`problem with request: ${e.message}`);
});

request.end();

var stdin = process.openStdin();

console.log('Press <enter> to exit..');

stdin.addListener("data", function(d) {
    console.log('exiting..');
    process.exit(1);
});
```